# Using yahoo finance API - Undefined output

Tags: javascript, yahoo-finance

I'm currently trying to use the `yahoo-finance` open source API from npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/yahoo-finance), but I can't seem to be getting the ouput desired (price and details for Tesla) as I keep seeing "undefined" when I run this code:

```
let yahooFinance = require('yahoo-finance');

let yahoo = yahooFinance.quote({
    symbol: 'TSLA',
    modules: ['price', 'summaryDetail']       
  }, function(err, quote) {
    console.log(quote);
    {
      price: {
        
      },
      summaryDetail: {
        
      }
    }
  });

console.log(yahoo)
```

Output goes something like this:

```
<ref *1> Promise [Object] {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _cancellationParent: <ref *2> Promise [Object] {...
```

Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try my code it also works but not exactly like the given example.

```
var request = require("request");

var url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/foo";

request(url, function (error, response, body) { 
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {  
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Yahoo Finance API: ",data)      
    };
});
```